# Interpolating missing data in cumulative timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, nan

I have a time-series `dataframe` with a cumulative data column. Data drops at night-time leaving me with `NaN` values, and picks up with first data read in the morning.

I would like to interpolate the data so that all `NaN` values take on the value of the last known `float`/valid number. Is this readily possible with `.interpolate()`?

Comment: You can just sort on time and do `ffill()`.

Comment: wow, i cannot believe i didn't know about `ffill()`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from @Quang Hoang above wiht `ffill()`